# Download directories using wget command

Tags: bash, shell, url, directory, wget

I need to download only rpm files from different directories. Here is my code -

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    # Download Only rpm file from certain directory.
    # wget
    #   -4 = only ipv4 
    #   -A = accept list
    #   -r = reccursively
    #   -R = reject list
    #   -c = continue
    #   -e = execute command
    #  --exclude-directories = take list

    # Create a directory
    mkdir mrepo

    # Enter into the directory
    cd mrepo

    # RPM URL
    repo_url="http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/"       

    # Repo rpm
    repo_download=('5.2.20' '5.2.22' '6.0.0')
    # Exclude directories
    exclude_dir=('*_Beta')
    # Download all rpm packages                     
    for i in "${repo_download[@]}"; do
      echo $i/
      echo ${repo_url}/$i/
      # wget -A rpm -rc -e robots=off --reject "index.html*" ${repo_url}/$i/
      wget -A zip -rc -e robots=off --reject "index.html*" ${repo_url}/$i/
    done

    # Tar the downloaded rpm 
    tar -cvzf missingrepo.tgz --exclude=./*.sh .
```

My target is to

1. Download only rpm file
2. From specific directories; so I created a list of those directories and pass it on `for` loop. Apparently, it seems working. But actually not.
3. It is executed, it enters the desired directory. Ignoring all directories which are before this version. Here **5.2.20** and download the rpm files from this directory. but when it finished downloading of that directory, it execute `wget` command to all directories and starts downloading rpm file from all directories. :-(
4. Tried to use `--exclude-directories=` to exclude unnecessary sub directories. But `--exclude-directories` argument is not working.
   PS: To execute rapidly and test purpose, I use zip files to download.

   `wget -A zip -rc -e robots=off --reject "index.html*" --exclude-directories=exclude_dir  ${repo_url}/$i/`

Any help would be really helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-np|--no-parent` and `-l|--level` command line option of `wget`.

> Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.

> Specify recursion maximum depth level. If you want to download all the files from one directory, use ‘-l 1’ to make sure the recursion depth never exceeds one.

So the command should look like this `wget -A zip -np -r -l 1 -c -e robots=off --reject "index.html*" ${repo_url}/${i}/`. `--reject "index.html*"` is useless in my mind. And you should correct `repo_url` in your script to `"http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox"` without the trailing slash. So you get

```
wget -A zip -np -r -l 1 -c -e robots=off ${repo_url}/${i}/
```

The result is then

```
mrepo/download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.20/VirtualBoxSDK-5.2.20-125813.zip
mrepo/download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.22/VirtualBoxSDK-5.2.22-126460.zip
mrepo/download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.0/VirtualBoxSDK-6.0.0-127566.zip
```

Just to be complete, a short version of the script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

repo_url="https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox"
repo_download=('5.2.20' '5.2.22' '6.0.0')

for i in "${repo_download[@]}"; do
  wget -A zip -np -r -l 1 -c -e robots=off ${repo_url}/${i}/
done
```

Comment: Ok. I'll check. What about the `--exclude-directories` argument. If the URL has any subdirectory lets say in `5.2.20`, I have that sub-directory names `5.2.20-src` and it also contains zip, rpm files and I need to exclude.

Comment: Enhanced answer with `-l` option

Comment: it now only download the folders not the content. Don't know where went wrong

Comment: Added a short version of the script to the answer.